Unable to negotiate with <ip> no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
I have recently moved to a Debian VM for my FreePBX install. Before I was able to connect my code editor using Secure FTP, but since my move I'm not able to and I'm getting the following log:
<server hostname> sshd[644596]: Unable to negotiate with <client ip> port 55208: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]

I have found a couple of solutions on this website, but those don't seem to work. One of them:
Add the following to .ssh/config
Host *
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss

I think I have tried all options mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/836048/ssh-returns-no-matching-host-key-type-found-their-offer-ssh-dss
Is this Ubuntu only or should this work in bare Debian too?

Adding the following lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config solved the issue for me:
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

